# Rename directories with a trimmed name

Tags: bash, rename

I have many subdirectories where each directory contains a time at the end of its name. I want to remove this. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
.
├── ACRA
│   └── acra2017-12-25 16:01:57
├── Activiti
│   └── Activiti2017-05-02 17:15:37
```

to

```
.
├── ACRA
│   └── acra2017-12-25
├── Activiti
│   └── Activiti2017-05-02
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type d -name '*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' -exec sh -c '
    for d; do mv -- "$d" "${d% *}"; done
' findsh {} +
```

Before actually running the script, you may put an `echo` between `do` and `mv` to be sure that the correct `mv` operation will apply.

- `-type d`: Select only directories
- `-name '*[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'`: A glob pattern to match only names with those times at the end.
- `for d; do mv -- "$d" "${d% *}"; done`: For each directory found, apply the `mv` operation, renaming it. The `${d% *}` removes from the filename all after (and including) the last space.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and the Perl `rename` utility:

```
find . -type d -name "* [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" \
  -exec rename -n 's/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$//' {} \;
```

Remove the `-n` option if the output looks as expected.